# Firebase real time database transaction while offline

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase package in a react native application and am trying to understand how transactions work in offline. I am trying to write a transaction using the following code

```
firebase.database().ref('locations').transaction(locations => {
    ... my location modification logic,

    return locations
})
```

However, if I go offline before writing the transaction and have not accessed the reference previously and therefore have no cached data, `locations` is null.

There is this small tidbit in Firebase's official documentation

> Note: Because your update function is called multiple times, it must
>   be able to handle null data. Even if there is existing data in your
>   remote database, it may not be locally cached when the transaction
>   function is run, resulting in null for the initial value.

Which leads me to believe I should wrap the entire transaction logic inside

```
if (locations) {
   ... my location modification logic
}
```

But I still don't fully understand this.  Is the following assumption correct?

1. Submit transaction
2. If offline and cached data exists, apply transaction against cached data, then apply towards current data in remote when connectivity resumes
3. If offline and no cached data exists, do not apply transaction. Once connectivity resumes, apply transaction to current data in remote
4. If online, immediately apply transaction

If these assumptions are correct, then the user will not immediately see their change in case #3, but in case #2 it will 'optimistically' update their cached data and the user will feel like their action immediately took place. Is this how offline transactions work? What am I missing?

Comment: IIRC, transactions immediately fail if you are offline, since they require validating data against the server to succeed. It will not "wait and reapply".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database (and Firestore) don't support offline transactions at all.  This is because a transaction must absolutely round trip with the server at least once in order to safely commit the changes to the data, while also avoiding collisions with other clients that could be trying to change the same data.

If you're wondering why the SDK doesn't just persist the callback that handles the transaction, all that can be said is that persisting an instance of an object (and all of its dependent state, such as the values of all variables in scope) is actually very difficult, and is not even possible in all environments.  So, you can expect that transaction only work while the client app is online and able to communicate with the server.

Comment: I don't doubt your answer at all but I'm still confused. As far as I can tell, Firebase's official documentation does not state offline transactions are not supported, and in the section immediately under the section on transactions, "Write data offline", it seems to state the opposite by saying every client has a local copy of the data that changes are written to first, then synchronized after. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data_offline

Comment: Everything but transactions follow the general rules of local cache.  If you found the documentation confusing, feel free to voice your concerns with the documentation with the "send feedback" button at the top right.

Comment: Gotcha, I will definitely do that. Thanks!